If $(X,Y) \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, is it true that $P(X \leq 0, Y \leq 0) \geq P(X \leq 0) P(Y \leq 0)$
Let's say that $(X,Y)$ is bi-variate normal, with both $X$ and $Y$ being standard normal.
Let's say $A = \{X \leq a\}$, $B = \{Y \leq a\}$, for some real number $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
In this case, is it true that $P(A) P(B) \leq P(A \cap B)$?
This isn't true for general events $A$ and $B$, but I feel like it should hold in this particular case.
Thank you.

No, because the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ may be negative.  For instance, let $a = 0$, and $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal with mean vector $\mu = (0,0)$ and variance-covariance matrix $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -\frac{3}{4} \\ -\frac{3}{4} & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$  Then the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal, and $\Pr[X \le 0] = \Pr[Y \le 0] = \frac{1}{2}$, but $$\Pr[(X \le 0) \cap (Y \le 0)] = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\arcsin \frac{3}{4}}{2\pi} < \frac{1}{4}.$$
In fact, for correlation $\rho$, the joint probability is
$$\Pr[(X \le 0) \cap (Y \le 0)] = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\arcsin \rho}{2\pi},$$ which immediately demonstrates precisely when the claimed inequality is not satisfied in the case $a = 0$, and in the general case, there is no reason to believe that the claimed inequality would hold for $\rho < 0$.

By request, the computation for the case $a = 0$ is as follows.  The joint density is
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2 - 2\rho x y + y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right),$$
which suggests the Cartesian-to-polar transformation
$$(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta), \quad dy \, dx = r \, dr \, d\theta.$$
The joint probability is
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[(X \le 0) \cap (Y \le 0)]
&= \int_{x=-\infty}^0 \int_{y=-\infty}^0 f(x,y) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \int_{\theta = -\pi}^{-\pi/2} \int_{r = 0}^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{r^2(1 - \rho \sin 2\theta)}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right) r \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{2\pi} \int_{\theta = -\pi}^{-\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{1 - 2\rho \sin 2\theta} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\arcsin \rho}{2\pi}.
\end{align}$$

Nice! How did you compute the probability that X and Y are less than 0?

@J.K. See edits to my answer; the details of the computation are left as an exercise.

Thank you @heropup!
